# In sequelize model, how to create a dynamic model where fields will be initialized after getting the data from DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am wondering how can I create a dynamic model where all the fields will be called from the database and then the model will be initialized, In the below code I am trying to do the same first calling the fields from the database and then I am doing data structure and then inside the Result.init I am calling the getColumn function. But when I call this model I am getting undefined.

```
module.exports = async (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Result extends Model {}

    const getColumn = async () => {
        const tableColumns = `SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS columnName
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'results';`;
        const data = await sequelize.query(tableColumns);
        return data[0].reduce(
            (acc, cur) => {
                if (cur.columnName !== 'id') {
                    acc[cur.columnName] = {
                        type: DataTypes.STRING,
                        allowNull: true,
                    };
                    return acc;
                }
                return acc;
            },
            {
                roll: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
            },
        );
    };

    Result.init(await getColumn(), {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'result',
        underscored: false,
    });
    return Result;
};
```

On here I am calling the result model and getting undefined.

```
const SuperDao = require('./SuperDao');
const models = require('../models');

const Result = models.result;
console.log(Result);

class ResultDao extends SuperDao {
    constructor() {
        super(Result);
    }
    async uploadBulkResult(data) {
        return Result.bulkCreate(data);
    }
}

module.exports = ResultDao;
```

Comment: You didn't show `models` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I used async that's why I was getting undefined.
This was the issue.

```
module.exports = async (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
```